# rails3-jquery-autocomplete clear field if no data available

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I am using rails3-jquery-autocomplete. Is it possible to clear the value of an autocomplete field if the autocomplete returns no results? I'm trying to prevent users from submitting values we don't have in database.

Comment: You could always filter submissions through ActiveModel, since there's always work-arounds for javascript 'safety scripts'.

Comment: True, however, I want the user to know immediately that the entry won't be used.

Comment: Can you paste your autocomplete helper call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an older version but I implemented a `change` handler for the `autocomplete()` call.

```js
$('input[data-autocomplete]').live('focus', function(i){
  $(this).autocomplete({
    // ...
    change: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);

      // blank if nothing was selected
      if (!ui.item) {
        $this.val(null);

        var id_selector = $this.attr('id_element');

        if (id_selector)
          $(id_selector).val(null);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Absolutely. Beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use select callback function to check if the value is correct, if its not then clear this input

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```