# rails3-jquery-autocomplete: how to extend select function?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm using the rails3-jquery-autocomplete 1.0.9 with Rails 3.2.8.

I'm trying to replace a combobox (`<select>`) with an autocomplete. Like a combobox, if the user chooses a value, I want to update an id in the database. Also like a combobox, it should not be possible to choose an invalid value.

One aspect of this is that if the user starts typing in the field, but leaves the field without selecting a value from the pick list, the field itself, and the corresponding hidden #to_contact_id field, should be blanked out.

Here are the field definitions:

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag "to_contact_name", '',
      autocomplete_contact_display_name_messages_path,
      :id_element => "#to_contact_id",
      :value => to_contact_name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :to_contact_id, :id => "to_contact_id" %>
```

My plan was to set a flag when the user selects an item from the pick list, then check the flag on blur (lost focus). I found an example of overriding an autocomplete function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794189/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-clear-field-if-no-data-available), and coded this Javascript:

```
var picklist_value_selected = false;

$('input[data-autocomplete]').focus(function() {
  // add autocomplete event handler on focus
  $(this).autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
      picklist_value_selected = true;
    }
  });
});

$('input[data-autocomplete]').blur(function() {
  // If user leaves field without selecting value, clear values.
  if (!picklist_value_selected) {
    $(this).val('')
    $('#to_contact_id').val('');
  };
});
```

The problem is, when I *override* `select` as above, the "default" functionality doesn't execute, meaning that #to_contact_id is never filled in in the first place.

I assume what I need is to *extend* the `select` rather than overriding it, so both my code and the rails3-jquery-autocomplete base code execute? How do I do that? Various attempts like the following either do not get called or complain about undefined methods:

```
$.extend($(this).autocomplete, {
  select: function(event, ui) {
    picklist_value_selected = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use autocomplete's [change event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change). It is triggered when the field is blurred, if the value has changed and let's you know which item (if any) was selected. You can bind to it like this:

```
$('input[data-autocomplete]').bind('autocompletechange', function(event, ui) {
    if(!ui.item) {
        // clear the fields
    }
});
```

Update:

> Since I fought with it so long today, I'd still be interested in knowing how to extend a function.

Look [here](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/integration/public/javascripts/autocomplete-rails.js#L48). This is where the autocomplete is initialized. `select` is an anonymous function passed as an option to autocomplete. You can extend it like this (hope the code is self explanatory):

```
var originalSelect = $('input[data-autocomplete]').autocomplete('option', 'select');
$('input[data-autocomplete]').autocomplete('option', 'select', function(event, ui) {
    originalSelect.call(this, event, ui);
    doSomeOtherStuff();
});
```

This is however not a good code, because `select` is an event, so if you want to do more stuff when it's called you can just bind another function to it. That way both the original and your function will be called without hacking like in my previous example:

```
$('input[data-autocomplete]').bind('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui) {
    doSomeOtherStuff();
});
```

Comment: Helpful, thanks. Almost the same as suggested in the article I cited, but I had missed the fact that `ui.item` is actually populated with the newly selected value, if any. Since I fought with it so long today, I'd still be interested in knowing how to *extend* a function. Maybe it's really difficult? Couldn't find good examples.

Comment: Thanks again, both of those examples of extension work. So to bind a new function to an existing event, you mash together the current function/event names? Never would have guessed that. Is the order of execution guaranteed, i.e. will my new function always execute first? I kind of like the "hack" for the more obvious control of execution sequence--and the more familiar call to the "super" of the function. The other syntax I found for "super" is, for example, `return $.ui.sortable.prototype._init.apply(this, arguments);` but I never could figure out the right namespace to call that on.

Comment: I just saw that a patch to rails3-jquery-autocomplete, addressing the issue of clearing values, was merged four days ago and released as 1.0.10. It caused issues for me so I'm still on 1.0.9. See the discussion here:  https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/pull/167.