# Rails (3.2.9) autocomplete work like jQuery combobox?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an autocomplete field on my form that is working however I need to force the user to select one of the values from the list (with autocomplete, the user is not restricted to an item from the list -- it's a textfield and they can enter whatever they want).  The [jQuery combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) adds the additional functionality that I require.  Can anyone help me add that additional functionality to my form -- is there a tutorial or exmample I can follow?

#### Here's what I have so far (and it is working - Thank you Ryan Bates )

#### view - new.html.erb

```
 <%= f.input :widget_name, input_html: { data: { autocomplete_widget_source: widgets_list_path } } %>
```

#### controller

```
def list
  @widgets = Widget.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  render json: @widgets.map(&:name)
end
```

#### JQuery

```
jQuery ->
  $('#model_widget_name').autocomplete
  source: $('#model_widget_name').data('autocomplete-widget-source')
```

I tried using a simple collection_select, but the document is too large (10,000 items) because of the size of the select list.

```
<%=  collection_select :model, :widget_id, Widget.all, :id, :name, selected: @model.widget_id  -->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found the answers I was looking for.

I added the following

```
jQuery ->
  $('#model_widget_name').bind 'autocompletechange', (event, ui) ->
    if (!ui.item)
      $(this).val('');
```

Does this make sense?  Do I need more?

THANK YOU TO THE FOLLOWING:

- mechianicalfish on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096619/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-how-to-extend-select-function)
- Mark Berry at [MCB
  Systems](http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2012/10/convert-a-select-drop-down-box-to-an-autocomplete-in-rails/)